# Convert BinaryString to ByteArray - Java

Tags: java, ajax, servlets

I have a requirement to send docx/pdf files as email. So I am sending file as Binary string from ajax to Java Servlet & converting it to InputStream & then pass it as ByteArray to ByteArrayDataSource. I am getting email with attachment but the pdf file is empty. Below is the code:-

Ajax :

```
var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'SendAttachments',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: jQuery.param({positionApllied:"tester",
                        Name:"John",
                        fileName:"invoice.pdf",
                        fileType:"application/pdf",
                        attachment:reader.result}),
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                    {},
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                    {}
                })
            }
            reader.readAsBinaryString(file)
```

Java Servlet :

```
    String filecontent =  request.getParameter("attachment");
    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(filecontent.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    byte[] bucket = new byte[32*1024]; 
    ByteArrayOutputStream result = null; 
    try  {
      try {
        result = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bucket.length);
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while(bytesRead != -1){
          bytesRead = stream.read(bucket);
          if(bytesRead > 0){
            result.write(bucket, 0, bytesRead);
          }
        }
      }
      finally {
          stream.close();
      }
    }
    catch (IOException ex){
    }


    ByteArrayDataSource source = new ByteArrayDataSource(result.toByteArray(), fileMime);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Instead of using reader.readAsBinaryString(file), Use reader.readAsDataURL(file). And pass the parameter as

```
data: jQuery.param({positionApllied:applied,
                        cName:cname,
                        fileName:fname,
                        fileType:ftype,
                        attachment:reader.result.split(",")[1]}),
```

And in Java, Decode the string.

```
String filecontent =  request.getParameter("attachment");

    byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(filecontent);

    InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedBytes);

    byte[] bucket = new byte[32*1024]; 
    ByteArrayOutputStream result = null; 
    try  {
      try {
        result = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bucket.length);
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while(bytesRead != -1){
          bytesRead = stream.read(bucket);
          if(bytesRead > 0){
            result.write(bucket, 0, bytesRead);
          }
        }
      }
      finally {
          stream.close();
      }
    }
    catch (IOException ex){
    }

    ByteArrayDataSource source = new ByteArrayDataSource(result.toByteArray(), fileMime);
```